# Why Motion AI Bot integrated in Smooch doesn't show correctly html formatting?

Tags: html, telegram, chatbot, smooch

I have created a bot in Motion.ai that use html formatting. When I use the bot in Telegram through Smooch the html formatting is not respected. The messages show directly the html tags like

```
Hello my name is <b>Shoppy</b>!
```

Is it normal or I'm doing something wrong?

I got the same problem if I use the Smooch web messaging integration.

Example of web integration:[bot web integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HZ3A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal.

As far as messaging channels go, Telegram is somewhat unique here in terms of their HTML formatting support. Smooch.io's unified messaging API aims to support all features across all messaging channels, but unfortunately it doesn't cover the HTML formatting use case yet. For now Smooch.io will escape HTML tags coming from Motion.ai, as you observe in Telegram and in the web messenger.

Disclaimer: I work on Smooch

Answer (score 0):

> HTML style
>
> To use this mode, pass HTML in the parse_mode field when using
>   sendMessage.

[For more info...](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style)